# Bootstrap Accordion is not working after expand all the element in the 3 panels in my application?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I click on `Expand All` it expands all the panels elements and then it collapses the panels by clicking on each panel. But problem when i want to expand panel1, panel2 and panel3. If panel2 is expanded then panel1 and panel3 should be collapsed and so on.

```js
$('#Expand').on('click', function() {
  $('#accordion .panel-collapse').collapse('show');
});
```

```css
#Icon .collapse-toggle:after {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content: "\e114";
  float: right;
  color: grey;
}

#Icon .collapse-toggle.collapsed:after {
  content: "\e080";
}
```

```html
    <a id="Expand" href="#">Expand All</a>
  </span>

  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" id="Icon">
        <a class="collapse-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1">panel1</a>
      </div>
      <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" id="Icon">
        <a class="collapse-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2">panel2 </a>
      </div>
      <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" id="Icon">
        <a class="collapse-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3">panel3 </a>
      </div>
      <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/mKWWYd

```
var chk = true;
$('#Expand').click(function() {
    $("#accordion .panel-collapse").each(function(i, v) {
        console.log(i);
        console.log(v);
        if ($(this).hasClass("in")) {
            chk = true;
            $(this).collapse('hide');
        } else {
            chk = false;
            $(this).collapse('show');
        }
    })
});

$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    if (chk) {
        $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not working as expected. If you click on expand, it expands all the panels and also if I click on each panel, it collapses. But again if click on panel1, panel2 then these both panel will be opened. But I want to hide panel1 if i click on panel2. The same works when the page loads in your code also.

Comment: I am not getting what you want? can you explain again. It's quite confusing!!

Comment: if you run your code and then click on panel. it all works fine. if you click on panel1 then panel1 expands and if if you click on panel2 then panel1 gets collapsed. The same thing i want when I click on Expand All. When I click on Expand All, all the panel expands but collapsing is not working as expected. I hope I made it clear.

Comment: Bhumi, it is still not working as expected. Please follow this step and see the result. When your page loads, click on each panel and see how one is expanding and another is collapsing. But the same thing does not work once you click on expand all. It expands all the panel. Now you have to click each panel to collapse. I think that is also fine. But, again, you click on each panel. It only expands but not collapsed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172886/discussion-between-user9895-and-bhumi-shah).